# Does a UIPanGestureRecognizer take precedence over the -touchesMoved: method?

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I'm not sure about this, but does a UIPanGestureRecognizer take precedence over a UIView's touch handling methods when it is added to that view?  That is, will I still receive `-touchesMoved:` method calls from that view, or will I only get the callback from the gesture recognizer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it takes precedence over the touches handling callbacks. And  it calls `touhesCancelled` before giving it to `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, if you have implemented it.